# Getting selected item values in Datalist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using an ImageButton in Datalist and want to store the selected items value in a varible to process it further. How to get the data upon button click. The data i need are Productid, name,price and so on. Any help?
Code for Datalist is

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" Width="100%" 
    onselectedindexchanged="DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged" 
    oncancelcommand="DataList1_CancelCommand" oneditcommand="DataList1_EditCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table class="style3" style="border: medium solid #000000; width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="3" width="50%" valign="top">
                   <center style="border-width: thin; border-color: #000000; height: 149px; border-right-style: solid;"> 
                       <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink9" runat="server" Height="100px" 
                           NavigateUrl='<%# "~/ProductDetails.aspx?ProductId=" + Eval("Product_id") %>' 
                           Width="100px" style="margin-left: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px"> 
                           <asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "images/" + Eval("Category")+"/"+Eval("Sub_category")+"/"+Eval("image") %>'   ToolTip='<%# Eval("Product_name") %>' /></asp:HyperLink>
                       <br />
                       <br />
                       <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" 
                           Text='<%# "Price : " + Eval("Price") + " Rs." %>'></asp:Label>
                   </center>
                 </td>
                <td class="style6" style="width: 50%">
                   <center style="border-bottom-style: solid; border-width: thin; border-color: #000000"> 
                       <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
                           Text='<%# Eval("Product_name") %>' ToolTip='<%# Eval("Product_name") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
                   </center>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style7" valign="top">
                    <center style="border-width: thin; border-color: #000000; height: auto; border-bottom-style: solid;">
                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Product_info") %>'></asp:Label></center>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style5">
                    <center>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" Height="49px" 
                            ImageUrl="~/images/add to cart.jpg" onclick="ImageButton3_Click" 
                            Width="135px" />
                    </center>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

I want that upon Image Button Click the selected Rows Values should get stored in Cart table  and for this i need to store this values to my Backend code to and need atleast Productid value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a `string` from what you want, and put them in `CommandArgument` property of `ImageButton`, and in `Server Side` handler, read the that string from `sender` which is passed to handler, and for make it easy, you can create string from what you want, in `JSON` string, and in server, `deserialize` the `stringified` data to a `Type`,
you can set the `CommandArgument` like this:

```
<asp:ImageButton 
    ID="ImageButton3" 
    runat="server" 
    Height="49px" 
    CommandArgument='<%# "{\"Product_id\": \""+ Eval("Product_id") +"\", \"Price\": \"" + Eval("Price") + "\"}" %>'
    Width="135px" 
    OnClick="ImageButton3_Click" />
```

and in the server side handler of the `ImageButton` you need this:

```
protected void ImageButton3_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer o = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    Argument arg = o.Deserialize<Argument>(((ImageButton)sender).CommandArgument);
}

class Argument
{
    // these property names, must be the same with what you set in 
    // CommandArgument where you write, for example : ... ='<%# "{\"Product_id\": \""+  ...

    // i assume the type of Product_id is guid
    public Guid Product_id { get; set; }

    // i assume the type of Price is decimal
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

** OR **

you can use the `OnItemCommand` event of DataList Like this:

1- set the handler :

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server"
    OnItemCommand="DataList1_OnItemCommand">
```

2- set the `CommandName` property of `ImageButton` which used as a key like:

```
<asp:ImageButton 
    ID="ImageButton3" 
    runat="server"
    CommandName="ImageButtonClick"
/>
```

3- create some `HiddenFields` Containing what you want on the server in `ItemTemplate` tag of your `DataList` Like:

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server"
    OnItemCommand="DataList1_OnItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>

        <asp:ImageButton 
            ID="ImageButton3" 
            runat="server"
            CommandName="ImageButtonClick"

        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldProductID"
            runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Product_id") %>' />  

        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenFieldPrice"
            runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Price") %>' />  

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

4- implement the server side `OnItemCommand` handler of your `DataList`, and getting created `HiddenFields` and reading its values, like:

```
protected void DataList1_OnItemCommand(object source, DataListCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "ImageButtonClick")
        {
            Guid ID = Guid.Parse(((HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("HiddenFieldProductID")).Value);

            decimal Price = Convert.ToDecimal(((HiddenField)e.Item.FindControl("HiddenFieldPrice")).Value);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for help. I am unable to understand 1st method but yes Learned something new from Second method...Thanks ones again for this great help.