# Convert a Datalist item to an int

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can I convert a datalist item that is fed from a `SqlDataSource` to an `Int`?

Here is what I am trying to do.
I am trying to compare input from a textbox to the item displayed in the datalist which gets its data from a datasource.

```
int Min;
        Min = Convert.ToInt32(TextBox1.Text);
        int Min2;
        Min2 = Convert.ToInt32(DataList1.Items);
        if (Min >= Min2)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "AlertMessage",
"alert('Please make sure that the off bench time is smaller than the on the clock time.');
", true);
        }
```

Comment: You can start by asking a: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please see this post for the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22412441/getting-selected-item-values-in-datalist

Comment: Have you tried the .GetData() method on the datalist?

Comment: Added more details

Comment: I removed the sql-server tag as this doesn't have anything to do with sql-server.

Comment: Does anyone have any advice?